# Pass variable from php scope to another php scope in same page

Tags: php, scopes

I want to get a value of variable stored in another php scope

```
<?php
    $count=3;
?>

<?php
    echo($count); //does not print the value
?>
```

The 2 php scopes are in the same page.

Comment: Yes it does: http://codepad.org/1ubSUqUU

Comment: what you posted should work, are they in functions?

Comment: oops , sorry i found where is the problem in my program

Comment: @israa Please remove your question in that case.

Comment: the question can not be deleted because of there is comments ! :(

Answer (score 2):

```
In your case , it MUST show 3
```

Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

This link is full of examples like the one you have listed here.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

try using var_dump($varname)

you dont need to put the parenthesis  (around the var)

```
<?php
$count=3;

echo $count; //will work

var_dump($count) //when in doubt, look at what is in the variable

?>
```